# How can I create custom Live Templates with an Intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to create a custom Live Template that will be available with my plugin. I know how to create custom Live Templates using the Settings dialog, but I want to be able to *distribute the Live Template as part of my plugin:*

- How is the *Live Template* defined within the plugin?
- Where is the entry point to register it with the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

using 12.1.5
I was able to accomplish this after looking at the groovy plugin source.

1. Go ahead and create your template using the settings dialog.  It will store the resulting xml file somewhere under `%home%/.Ideawhatever/config/templates` in `group_name.xml`
2. Copy this file into `project/resources/liveTemplates`
3. Create an implementation of `DefaultLiveTemplatesProvider` and implement as follows:

   ```
    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultLiveTemplateFiles()
     {
        return new String[] {"liveTemplates/group_name"};
     }
   ```
4. add the following under extensions in your plugin.xml

   ```
   defaultLiveTemplatesProvider implementation="com.tridium.intellij.NiagaraTemplatesProvider"
   ```

Comment: Regarding the user template directory location: In IntelliJ 14 on OS X, the file is in Users ▸ $you ▸ Library ▸ Preferences ▸ IntelliJIdea14 ▸ templates

Comment: It's worth nothing that you should mark resource folder as **Sources Root** or **Resources Root** (context-menu -> Mark Directory As -> Resources Root)