# Can you bundle live templates into a plugin/package in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, live-templates

I have a selection of live templates / snippets specific to a particular framework that I would like to distribute as a plugin/package. Is it possible to do this for PHPStorm/WebStorm?

I have managed to do this for the Sublime Text 2/3 editor very easily and my package is now accessible via the package manager. In short I'm wanting to do the same for PHPStorm, allowing people to download my live templates as a plugin from the plugin repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use answer from this question [How can I create custom Live Templates with an Intellij plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256640/how-can-i-create-custom-live-templates-with-an-intellij-plugin).
You need to create DefaultLiveTemplateProvider and register it in plugin.xml