# How can i provide Custom code-styles within a plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Basically my task is nearly a copy of [1], the only thing i want to achieve is, to put the generated codestyle.xml into a plugin to share this.

So i have my codeStyle.xml in my resources folder under codestyles like this:
ressources/codestyles/codeStyle.xml

The reason behind this is, that we started using an internal plugin repo for intellij, and in that way it is easier for us to distribute the settings internally.

Maybe my approach is not the best one, but i am glad for any input regarding this ticket.

[1] [How can I create custom Live Templates with an Intellij plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256640/how-can-i-create-custom-live-templates-with-an-intellij-plugin)

Thank you
Simon

Comment: okay right now i am looking at an implmentation approach, which can work, but in fact for maintaining issues, i still would love to this with an simple xml file provided via plugin.

Comment: Well i see now that i have a lot of questions regarding plugin development and settings, maybe there is somekind of guru who has time for some more questions, i simply ask those here but i do not expect any answers, although those would be highly appreciated: (1) is there an easy way to simple move the whole config folder into a plugin in and put it in a repo for easier sharing (2) how can i modify codeTemplates, do i need another provider for this?

Comment: it lookss like this is sadly not possible, as a solution we swapped to project based settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like this is sadly not possible, as a solution we swapped to project based settings